# How can I remove double quote and extra space from string in php?

Tags: php

I have and extra space and double quote in my string so that I have a problem,
for example doubl quote and extra space `"32134131            "`

How do I resolved this ?

Comment: You mean like [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)?

Comment: `trim(str_replace('"', '', $yourstring))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use trim function to remove both sided extra characters

```
$str = '"32134131            "';
trim($str, "\" ");
```

In this code sample above, the `$str` is passed through the trim function which looks for and removes all `"` and  characters.

Comment: Only thing I'd say is that, by default, `trim()` removes a chunk of characters i.e. `\t \n\r\0\x0B` but that character mask will explicitly remove *only* spaces and double-quotes... just something to bear in mind.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
$character_mask = " \t"
$str = '"32134131            "';
return trim($str)
```